# Where to find wallet password after running "cleos create wallet --file"

Tags: wallet

I have followed the official EOS tutorial, https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets and seen how you can easily create a wallet using 'cleos create wallet --to-console'. This is fine, yet not safe for production as apparently the password will be stored in your bash history.

So I want to run "cleos create wallet --file ". I can't seem to find the wallet password in this directory however - even on mac when I show all my hidden files.

Is there something simple I am missing?

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It seems I got the commands slightly wrong,

cleos wallet create --file test.txt

will create it to this file test.txt

Problem is I've done this and I can't find the test.txt file anywhere now :/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a wallet password using `--file` you have also to provide the output filename which will contain the password... Like this: `cleos wallet create --name testwallet --file mytest.txt`. The file `mytest.txt` will contain only the password which is something like `PW5JcVaWB9dW3SrWwpKN...`. Moreover, if you use the flag `--name` you can choose the name you want for the wallet. If you don't use `--name`, the wallet name will be `default`.

Comment: Hi thanks so much, man I appreciate I came right. The problem was I was running it in a docker container, so I had to go find the generated password there!

Comment: for command which I am running from shell script `cleos wallet create --name sample --file walletfile.txt` getting error `ERROR: Failed to create file in specified path`